# Как правильно использовать semver и git flow в случае изменения версии и в dev и в release?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, git, git-flow

допустим я работаю в dev и версия приложения 1.0.0, выпускаю release приложения с версией 1.0.0.
В dev делаю исправление багов и меняю версию 1.0.1, ... 1.0.10 dev уходит дальше.
Но тут срочно необходимо сделать исправления в release(делаем коммиты в release ветке) идет по коммитам отличным от dev и похоже должны сделать изменение версии 1.0.1 и добавить это изменение в master и dev. Но в dev версия ушла уже намного дальше.

Возможно я не правильно понимаю semver и git flow. Как действовать в такой ситуации?

Comment: добавьте ещё одну циферку в конец версии и не мучайтесь

Comment: `В dev делаю исправление багов и меняю версию 1.0.1` или вот тут меняйте версию на 1.1.0 .... 1.10.0, а исправления выпускайте под 1.0.1

Comment: Спасибо! Жаль что теперь не могу отметить как лучший ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Semver](https://semver.org/) подразумевает, что номер версии состоит из

1. Мажорная версия
2. Минорная
3. Патч

(Мажорная.Минорная.Патч)

Когда вы выпускаете версию (релиз), то вы должны увелчить мажорную или минорную версию. То есть, если релизите версию 1.0.0, то deveop станет либо 2.0.0 (следующий мажорный релиз), либо 1.1.0 (следующий минорный релиз).

Исправление в релизе называется патч (или хотфикс), при исправлении увеличивается последнее число. То есть был релиз 1.0.0, тогда исправление будет 1.0.1